# Looking for an efficient way to retrieve a set of many-to-many children for each row with Entity Framework Core

Tags: c#, linq, query-optimization, asp.net-core-2.1, entity-framework-core-2.1

**Context:** I have a table of `Items` which each have a many-to-many to a dynamic set of descriptors called `Tags`. Each `Tag` belongs to a `TagType` which determines what kind of information that `Tag` represents (Size, Color, Shape, etc.). Each `Item` can only have a max of one `Tag` per `TagType`.

**Goal:** I'd like to display a table of all my `Items` and have a column in each row with a nested table of `<th>TagTypes</th>` and `<td>Tags</td>` with empty cells if the `Item` Doesn't have a `Tag` for that `TagType`.

**Problem:** The Linq query takes at least 30 seconds with just 5000 `Items`. I'm expecting to have 100k+ `Items`. I need to find a way to populate this information more efficiently.

---

**Models**: (omitting unrelated properties)

```
public class Item : BaseEntity
{
    public virtual ICollection<ItemTag> ItemTags { get; set; }
}
```

```
 public class ItemTag
{
    public Guid ItemId { get; set; }
    public virtual Item  Item {get; set;}

    public Guid TagId { get; set; }
    public virtual Tag Tag { get; set; }
}
```

```
public class Tag : BaseEntity
{
    [Required]
    [MaxLength(100)]
    public string Value { get; set; }

    [Required]
    public Guid TagTypeId { get; set; }
    public virtual TagType TagType {get;set;}

    public virtual ICollection<ItemTag> ItemTags { get; set; }
}
```

```
public class TagType : BaseEntity
{
    [Required]
    [MaxLength(50)]
    public string Name { get; set; }

    public int Position { get; set; }

    public virtual ICollection<Tag> Tags { get; set; } 
}
```

I then have a Display Model `DisplayItem` which is what I convert to Json and return.

```
public class DisplayItem
{
    public Guid Id { get; set; }
    public List<DisplayTag> ItemTags { get; set; }

    public DisplayItem(Item itm, IList<TagType> tts)
    {
        Id = itm.Id;
        ItemTags = GetDisplayTags(itm.ItemTags
            .Select(it => it.Tag).ToList(), tts);
    }

    public List<DisplayTag> GetDisplayTags(IList<Tag> tags, IList<TagType> tts)
    {
        return tts.Select(tt => new DisplayTag(tt.Name, 
            tags.FirstOrDefault(t => t.TagTypeId == tt.Id)?.Value ?? "  ")).ToList();
    }
}
```

**Query:**

```
public async Task<JsonResult> OnGetItemsAsync()
{
    TagTypes = await _context.TagType.OrderBy(tt => tt.Position).AsNoTracking().ToListAsync();
    return new JsonResult(await _context.Items
        .Include(itm => itm.ItemTags)
        .ThenInclude(it => it.Tag)
        .ThenInclude(t => t.TagType)
        .AsNoTracking()
        .Select(itm => new DisplayItem(itm, TagTypes))
        .ToListAsync());
}
```

The slowest part seems to be the `GetDisplayTags(itm.ItemTags.Select(it => it.Tag).ToList(), tts);` but I'm not sure how else I'd go about getting this information.

Comment: tip #1: only bring back the columns you really need

Comment: @JohnB That's why I'm using the Display Model. I did notice I could delay the .ToListAsync() a bit and put it at the end of my query. That didn't make much of a difference though.

Comment: What's the duration of the basic query itself? That is, `_context.Items.Include ... .AsNoTracking()`.

Comment: @GertArnold If I replace the call to `GetDisplayTags(itm.ItemTags
            .Select(it => it.Tag).ToList(), tts)` with an empty list in the Display Model, the initial query only takes ~2 seconds.

Comment: Approximately how many `ItemTags` do you have per `Item`?

Comment: Seems to me that each `TagType.Tag` is queried separately since you seem to have lazy loading enabled. Use `TagTypes = await _context.TagType.Include(tt => tt.Tag)`. You should always check the executed SQL statements in case of poor performance. I'm afraid it'll be an unpleasant surprise. That said, I can't imagine why you'd want to pull 100k+ items into memory in a normal application flow.

Comment: @IvanStoev At the moment I have 5 `ItemTags` per `Item`.

Comment: Hmm, I was thinking that `tags.FirstOrDefault(t => t.TagTypeId == tt.Id)` could be the culprit, but if `tags` are 5, the linear search is ok. How many tags do you have then (`tts.Count`)? Let count - you'll have 5000 * 5 * tts.Count comparison operations. Also have you measured the time to `await ... ToListAsync()` in order to see if the time is spent there and not in the Json serialization.

Answer (score 0):

Your query in OnGetItemsAsync doesn't know, what happens in your DisplayItem constructor, so you query returns the whole Items collection, collection of ItemTags for each Item and collection of Tags for each ItemTag and collection of TagType for each Tag, so you bring back a lot of unnecessary data. To prevent it you should remove includes from your query.
Also you can optimize the query which seems to you the slowest part. FirstOrDefault each time searches the whole collection for a mach. You can try

```
return tts.Select(tt => new DisplayTag(tt.Name, tags.Where(t=>t.TagTypeId==tt.Id).GroupBy(t=>t.TagTypeId).Select(tg=>tg.First()?.Value??" "))).ToList();
```

Then the query will return the collection of TagTypeId and won't have to search the whole collection for the first entry.

Comment: I'm not sure how else to get the information from those tables if I don't `.Include()` them? The reason I've turned off LazyLoading (`.AsNoTracking()`) for this query is that the Proxies being created were slowing the whole thing down significantly.

Comment: As for `tags.Where(t=>t.TagTypeId==tt.Id).GroupBy(t=>t.TagTypeId).Select(tg=>tg.First()?.Value??" ")`, The tags I'm passing in there are already just the ones that belong to that `Item` (maybe ~5 `Tags`). They are already guaranteed to be unique, so wouldn't grouping them just add unnecessary overhead?

Comment: @Anacronym when you are passing an Item into DisplayItem constructor, it stays in the data context, so it will lazy load any navigation property in needs. But I think, the best solution would be to move all queries and selections to the query into OnGetItemAsync, so EF could see all of it's elements. Or, for maximum optimization, move it to the database: write an sql function which would return just a set of data you need.